# How delegate DNS from NIC.ar to AWS-EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I've a Node.js back end running on a EC2 instance (AWS) and I've a NIC.AR domain registered.
So the problem is that `nic.ar` not allow add CNAME records. It allows to add HOST and IPv4 records through NS records.

Comment: This is the way the DNS works. The registry (nic.ar here) will delegate the domain to your nameservers. It is then up to you to configure those nameservers to have the records you want. Besides, this question not being related to programming is offtopic here. Look at [su] most probably, but read the help section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manage DNS within the AWS ecosystem you can use [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/).

In Route53 you’re going to create a “Hosted Zone” that is named the same as your domain. If your domain is mydomain.ar, then your Hosted Zone is going to be mydomain.ar.

Once your Hosted Zone is created you’ll notice that it has two default record sets. One is an SOA record, and the other is the nameserver NS records. You’ll notice that the NS records has four entries. Copy the first entry and head over to your domain management at NIC.AR and update the first name server with the first name server from you AWS hosted zone. Repeat for the second, and if possible the third and fourth.  Save the updated entries at NIC.AR and give it time to propagate.

Route53 now is handling your DNS and you’ll be able to create new record sets as necessary in your hosted zone.

Comment: Thanks, it work!!!! It is no away from that I did following the aws route 53 doc. but really thanks.

Comment: If i purchased domain.com and want to have www.domain.com forward to domain.com, how do I do that?